# How to tell babel where to look for plugins?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

How do you set the path for Babel plugins?

babel --presets='[es2015]' medalOTM.js

**Error: Couldn't find preset "[es2015]" relative to directory "."**

babel --presets='[node_modules/es2015]' medalOTM.js

**Error: Couldn't find preset "[node_modules/es2015]" relative to directory "."**

? ls -d node_modules/babel-preset*

node_modules/babel-preset-es2015

Comment: isn't it just `--presets=es2015`? Also I'd much rather put that in `.babelrc`

Comment: That's it! Thanks!